# Marshalling char* C function to C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, unmanaged, managed

I am trying to understand how to marshall the char* type by passing and modifying strings back and forth between managed & unmanaged code. Managed to unmanaged code seems to work fine, but the opposite does not work. Is IntPtr suited for this situation?

C

```
EXPORT char* CharTest(char* ptchar, unsigned char* ptuchar)
{
    ptchar[0] = 'x';
    ptchar[1] = 'y';
    printf("%s    %s\n", ptchar, ptuchar);
    return(ptchar);
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("Sandbox.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
extern static IntPtr CharTest(string ptchar, string ptuchar);

static void Main()
{
    string ptchar = "ptchar";
    string ptuchar = "ptuchar";

    Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(CharTest(ptchar, ptuchar)));
}
```

Output

```
xychar    ptuchar
x?J
```

Thank you!

Comment: There's a huge mess of who owns which bit of memory going on here. The marshaller is allocating new `char*` buffers for `ptchar` and `ptuchar`, and copying your strings into them. It's freeing those buffers immediately after the native call returns. However, you're then returning one of those buffers from your function -- but it's just been freed!

Comment: My first instinct would be to declare the method in C# as `extern static string CharTest(...);` and let the interop layer handle all the conversions. Did you try that?

Comment: That won't fix the problem, which is that you've messed up who owns what. If you're not following the ownership semantics which the marshaller gives you by default, you really need to fall back to passing `IntPtr` and doing the memory management yourself

Comment: Hello gentlemans and thank you for your answers,


@Heinzi Declaring as string instead of IntPtr seems to have fixed the issue, I feel a bit uneasy about having both the char* & unsigned char* "converted" as a string. Shouldn't I add additionnal marshalling information to the function declaration such as In Out or MarshalAs?

Comment: @canton7 If at the end of the native function the buffers gets freed, then how am I supposed to return the char* ? What do you mean by doing the memory management myself ? As a side note, I am very new to marshalling and I don't fully grab the concept yet, pardon my lack of experience.

Comment: @Eize If you need to return the same buffer which was passed to you, then you need to pass in an `IntPtr`, like I said. Allocate the input buffer manually with e.g. `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi`. You'll get the same `IntPtr` out, which you can convert back to a string with `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` and then free with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`

Comment: @canton7 Could be wrong, but if the return type from C was `string`, wouldn't the marshaller copy the string before doing any `free` on the parameter buffers?

Comment: @canton7 `Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(CharTest(Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(ptchar), Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(ptuchar))));` seems to work very nicely. I would like to ask you one more question, what is the difference passing IntPtr and string ? My guess would be that by doing the memory management myself, the parameter I pass are already perfectly formatted for native use, hence no need for extra marshalling operations.

Comment: @Eize Don't forget to release the memory which the `IntPtr` points to once you're done with it! By passing `IntPtr` you're bypassing the marshaller, so it won't be allocating memory for you or (more importantly here) freeing that memory.

Comment: @Charlieface You're probably right, but that feels like relying an implementation detail of the marshaller

Comment: @canton7 I see. Thank you everyone for your time and answers, my issue has now been resolved, wish you all a good day!

Comment: @Eize: The [default for P/Invoke string marshaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings#strings-used-in-platform-invoke) is `UnmanagedType.LPStr`, which seems to match your `char*` nicely, so I don't think additional marshaling information is required.

Comment: @Heinzi Actually that depends on `CharSet` but in this case OP has provided it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare the return type of the imported function as `string`

```cs
[DllImport("Sandbox.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
extern static string CharTest(string ptchar, string ptuchar);
```

But because of the fact that you are actually returning one of the parameters, you would have to rely on the marshaller not freeing the parameter buffer before copying the return buffer.

You have two further options:

- Marshal it yourself. Make sure to place it in a `try/finally` in case of exceptions

```cs
[DllImport("Sandbox.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
extern static IntPtr CharTest(IntPtr ptchar, string ptuchar);

static void Main()
{
    string ptchar = "ptchar";
    string ptuchar = "ptuchar";
    IntPtr ptcharPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        ptcharPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(ptchar);
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(CharTest(ptcharPtr, ptuchar)));
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptcharPtr);
    }
}
```

- Declare the parameter as `StringBuilder` which means it will be copied both ways. In this case you do not need to look at the return value as it will be the same as the parameter.

```cs
[DllImport("Sandbox.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
extern static IntPtr CharTest([In, Out] StringBuilder ptchar, string ptuchar);

static void Main()
{
    StringBuilder ptchar = new StringBuilder("ptchar");
    string ptuchar = "ptuchar";

    CharTest(ptchar, ptuchar);
    Console.WriteLine(ptchar);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your second solution would require the C parameter to be declared as `char** ptchar`...

Comment: @Heinzi Hum you might be right. I think `StringBuilder` should work though, have modified